# Rename multiple directories decrementing sequence number?

Tags: bash, rename

I have a directory which contains a number of subdirectories with names on the format `dir.##`. The prefix is always the same, and the suffix is 1-3 digits in a strictly incrementing sequence. Thus, something similar to:

```
dir.0
dir.1
dir.2
dir.3
...
dir.9
dir.10
dir.11
...
dir.298
dir.299
dir.300
```

First, I want to delete the first few such directories. This is trivial.

Then, I want to rename all subsequent directories to shift the numerical suffixes such that e.g. `dir.7` becomes `dir.0`, `dir.8` becomes `dir.1`, `dir.10` becomes `dir.3`, etc. That is, shift each suffix (treated as a number) by a given, constant offset.

**How do I perform such a rename operation** without renaming each directory separately and manually?

I'm okay with using a separate tool for it, but it would be nice if I can do it all in bash without "exotic" software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This decrementing can be done in a pretty low-tech way: generate the list, start at the beginning. It's not that easy to “productize” by handling all cases, but it's little more than a one-liner if you're willing to hard-code things like the maximum number of digits and to assume that there are no other files called `dir.*`. Using bash syntax, tuned towards less typing:

```
i=0
for x in dir.{?,??,???}; do
  mv "$x" "${x%.*}.$i"
  ((++i))
done
```

Note that it has to be `dir.{?,??,???}` and not `dir.*` to get `dir.9` before `dir.10`.

In zsh you could make this a little more robust at no cost, by using `<->` to expand to any sequence of digits and `(n)` to sort numerically (`dir.9` before `dir.10`).

```
i=0
for x in dir.<->(n); do
  mv $x ${x%.*}.$i
  ((++i))
done
```

Comment: The bash example (with Glenn's edit for the substitution expression) did exactly what I wanted. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
n=7   # number to delete
max=$(printf "%s\n" dir.* | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | sort -n | tail -1)
for (( i=0; i<n; i++)); do rm -r "dir.$i"; done
for (( i=n; i<=max; i++ )); do mv "dir.$i" "dir.$((i-n))"; done
```

Comment: The quotes in the rm and mv command arguments are not strictly necessary since we know the contents of the generated directory name will not contain whitespace.

Comment: while technically true, quoting is generally considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use graphical tool KRename.

Here are the steps:

1. choose files
2. choose option to rename files
3. turn on JavaScript plugin\
4. set field Prefix to empty, Suffix: empty,
   Filename: use original name, Extension: other extension:
   `[js;krename_extension-OFFSET]` where `OFFSET` is value that you
   need to decrement.